# Installation of Samsung Kies fails on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, kies

I am trying to install Samsung Kies on my HP Compaq laptop running Windows XP. However, it is not installing. Installation stops showing "No internet connection warning!!!" even if am connected to WiFi. I had downloaded the full setup from the Samsung's site but it is still not getting installed. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using XP service pack 3, please update .net framework and check firewall/user permission is not blocking samsung kies.

Comment: Yes am using service pack 3.i updated .net framework.Can you just tell me how to check users permission?? Also i disabled the firewall still its not getting installed showing "no internet connection!!!!".

Comment: you can use icacls, just type icacls in cmd and you will find the options.

Comment: I installed the kies thanksss a lott...But y s3 is not detecting in kies can ou help me in tat also???wat will be the problem??

Comment: happy to hear that it worked. regarding s3 please do a kies update and then try, did you tried with uninstalling kies from your machine ever before, if so there may be some corrupt registry values, try uninstalling kies along with the reg entry with any software like 'your uninstaller' and then install it. it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just try installing after connected to internet. Some Installers requires a working internet connection even if it does not have anything to download.